# Base64 encoded modifying just printable char

Tags: linux, bash, base64

I have a base64 string that contains not printable chars.

I want to modify just the printable one. But i can't use base64 -d because I will lost the not printable ones.

Is that a command that allow me to do that?

Example, if I do

```
echo "base64 string" | base64 -d | od -c
```

I obtain

```
0000000 004 002 254 334   0 202 003 362  \f  \0   0 202 003 354   0 202
0000020 003 350 002 002 006 021   0   -   0   )   0 036 002 004   A 343
0000040 271   | 002 003  \0 352 233 002 002 021 340 002 002  \0 232 002
0000060 001   . 004 006  \0  \f   ) 346 353 323  \f  \a   J   0   0   6
0000100   0   6
```

etc...

let's say I want to modify just the J 0 0  with J 0 1...I can do this?

UPDATE:

For the moment the solution was in convert and output the base64 decode into a file and then edit it with an HEX Editor.

So if you know some command line HEX Editor native included in linux please tell me

Comment: You're *decoding* `"base64 string"`, are you surprised you get "binary" data back?

Comment: @aioobe I know the problem I was looking for solving it....I mean i should not use base64 decode...

Comment: and every char even if is not printable can be write according is code....004 is not printable but the code it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try it on my system I get

> base64: invalid input

Since you want printable characters only, I'm suspecting that what you want is a base64 encoded string.

If so, you should skipe the `-d` option:

```
echo "base64 string" | base64 | od -c
```

---

If you really want to change some characters into others, you could use the `tr` (translate) command:

From `man tr`:

> `tr` - translate or delete characters

Comment: But in decoding with base64 I can lose some non printable char...this is what happens....

Comment: `base64` *encodes* arbitrary data to printable characters. `base64 -d` reverses this process. Obviously you may get non-printable characters as the result of the *decoding*. What's for sure is that whatever data you give to `base64 | base64 -d`, you'll get the same data back.